# Azure VHD Download Very Slow

Tags: powershell, azure

I am using the following code to download VHD images from my Azure cloud.  It is painfully slow download so I want to make sure this is the best way to do this.  If so is there any improvements I could do to make this download complete more quickly.

Thanks

```
$destinationVHD = "I:\AzureVHD";

$sourceVHDs | foreach-object{

 $sourceVHD = [System.Uri]$_;
 $destinationVhdPath = (Join-Path -path $destinationVHD -childpath $sourceVHD.Segments[2]);

 write-host "`n`rDownloading... ";
 write-host  $sourceVHD.Segments[2] 
 Write-Host "Saving to: " $destinationVhdPath;

 $duration = Measure-Command{
    Save-AzureVhd -Source $sourceVHD.AbsoluteUri -LocalFilePath $destinationVhdPath -NumberOfThreads 10
 }

 Write-Host "`t Save complete in: " $duration.Hours "hrs," $duration.Minutes "min," $duration "secs," $duration.TotalMilliseconds "millisecs"

}
```